# Can't find Window builder pro in eclipse indigo

Tags: java, windowbuilder, eclipse-indigo

I read that Eclipse Indigo has Window Builder Pro plugin installed but I don't see where is it. File/New/Project doesn't give me option to choose Window Builder Pro. How to find it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add this update site to Eclipse. 
http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/release/R201106211200/3.7/

I found it on this page http://eclipse.org/windowbuilder/download.php

Answer (score 2):

Seems as the project isn't fully finished for Indigo (http://eclipse.org/indigo/planning/SimultaneousReleaseOverview.php?action=project&projectid=tools.windowbuilder

Answer (score 2):

I too expected and understood WindowBuilder would come built into Indigo, but apparently they changed their mind last minute.  Instead they're 'announcing' "WindowBuilder, a world-class Eclipse-based GUI builder, is now available as an Eclipse open source project" as a new feature of Indigo, which is clearly not a new feature to indigo, as the open source plugin has had 2 releases for eclipse in it's open source format.

Source: http://www.eclipse.org/org/press-release/20110622indigo.php

Answer (score 1):

there is no window builder in indigo Java EE win 64 :(
and probably in other releases

Comment: I downloaded Indigo JEE for linux 32bit, release.

Answer (score 1):

there is also no egit and m2eclipse in indigo Java EE win 64

Comment: So, I want change my Helios. Egit and Window builder were main reasons to try Ingigo.

Answer (score 0):

http://eclipse.org/windowbuilder/download.php

In this URL you can find links to Update Site and Zipped Update Site for Eclipse 3.4 (Ganymede) up to 4.2 (Juno), just hyperlink address...

Comment: In my question I told that in Indigo should be WindowBuilder installed by default, but it's not case. I'm not asking how to manually install WindowBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

It's included in the Eclipse update sites (at least in Juno):

1. Goto - Menu > Help > Install New Software...
2. Select - Work With: Juno - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno
3. The WindowBuilder items are under "General Purpose Tools" (or use the filter)

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse Indigo, go to Menu > Help > Install New Software

- Navigate to Indigo - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo
- In the list, search for General Purpose Tools and expand it
- You will find WindowsBuilder core within this expanded group

Answer (score 0):

open the install new software site,then click add , paste this link http://archive.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/release/R201106211200/3.7/ in the location. 
it will work.