# GWT Wizards are not showing in the eclipse Wizards menu

Tags: eclipse, gwt, gwt-designer

The google documentation http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/wizards/gwt/uibinder_dialogbox.html shows GWT wizards in eclipse, however, on my system this is not displayed.  How do I get them to show?

Google docs

[image]

My System

[image]

I definitely have GWT installed in eclipse and can run GWT projects

**Here are my updated sites from the Help menu**

Eclipse 3.7 WindowBuilder Repo  http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/integration/3.7    Enabled

GWT Framework   http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7 Enabled

Indigo  http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo Enabled

Subclipse SVN   http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x    Enabled

The Eclipse Project Updates http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.7 Enabled

Comment: Are you using Java perspective?

Comment: yes, definately the java perspective (I am using eclipse Version: 3.7.1 also)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/tools/download-gwtdesigner.html

Comment: GWT Designer Core 2.4.2.r37x201110201837 com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.hosted.feature.feature.group Google, Inc.
  GWT Designer Editor 2.4.2.r37x201110201842 com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.editor.feature.feature.group Google, Inc.
  GWT Designer GPE 2.4.2.r37x201110220223 com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.gpe.feature.feature.group Google, Inc.

Comment: did you have to do this to see the designer in your screenshot? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454745/cant-find-window-builder-pro-in-eclipse-indigo   I had to do it and although GWT was installed, I had to re-install it in order to see the GWT designer

Comment: I have the following installed -> Eclipse 3.7 WindowBuilder Repo http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/integration/3.7.  I think I added this manually to get WindowBuilder Swing and SWT.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the full version of GWT Designer. Installing the GPE only gets you a stripped down version of GWT Designer (w/o any of its wizards).

Comment: What is the difference, how do I get the full version?

Comment: The latest GWT Designer for Kepler can be found here (http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2gwt/latest/4.3). The Google page that hosts the links hasn't been updated for this new version yet.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I was able to get the GWT Designer tools to work on Eclipse Juno:

1. I already had GWT 2.5.0 installed, with GWT Designer. However, I couldn't see the designer anywhere
2. At the same time, I did not have WindowBuilder installed on my Eclipse.
3. So I first installed the WindowBuilder plugin from the main Eclipse plugin repo
4. Then I uninstalled GWT Designer (all 3 packages or so that are included)
5. Restarted Eclipse
6. Re-installed GWT Designer
7. Restarted Eclipse
8. Went to File > New > WindowBuilder > GWT User Interface
9. Got a dialog saying that I needed to install additional WindowBuilder toolkits. "Click finish to install this toolkit"
10. Clicked finished, Eclipse did its thing, problem solved =)

Not sure all the steps are required. I think the key is to have WindowBuilder installed with your GWT Designer, and remember to go to New > WindowBuilder instead of New > Google Web Toolkit