# GWT plugin - Eclipse Kepler 4.3 - cannot find toolbar button as "create a Java project with GWT support"

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, eclipse-plugin, gwt-rpc

I have **eclipse kepler 4.3** and I installed gwt plugin from here

> https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.3

I installed everything except android related tools; As I can see it the plugin installed gwt sdk 2.5 by default and it is fine; I restarted eclipse... but I cannot find the "create a Java project with GWT support" button on the toolbar :( I used to have the button in eclipse indigo and it helped to create gwt project with rpc support the client\server packages etc... So now I am a little confused where should I look at because the official tutorial shows how to [create client gwt app only](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/getting_started#creating) :(

To be more clear here is Eclipse Indigo toolbar screenshot :

[image]

So my question is how to create Java project with GWT support in eclipse kepler 4.3 and where is the "create a Java project with GWT support" button has really gone?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [GWT Wizards are not showing in the eclipse Wizards menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832802/gwt-wizards-are-not-showing-in-the-eclipse-wizards-menu)

possible duplicate of [can't create a New Web Application Project in eclipse indigo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479393/cant-create-a-new-web-application-project-in-eclipse-indigo)

Comment: @Splaktar Please it is not duplicate; The answer you give the link http://stackoverflow.com/a/8835910/592704 contains solution for Eclipse Indigo version only :( I have Eclipse Indigo installed and it works fine with all its gwt wizards! BUT my question is NOT about Indigo version BUT about "Eclipse Kepler" only; Kepler doesn't have gwt Designer wizards installed or its a bug or I don't know but I need to find out... This is why I ask this question.

Comment: ...and by the way, the google "Installing GWT Designer" page as https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/tools/download-gwtdesigner?csw=1 contains gwt designer for Indigo only :( There is no Kepler's one? :( So I don't get it is there really not all Kepler's gwt developing tools are downloadable yet or I am searching wrong places?

Comment: As stated in those questions that I linked, you don't get the full wizards when using GPE. You should be able to install the stand alone GWT Designer here (http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2gwt/latest/4.3). You can click on the GPE icon (blue circle with g) and select 'New Web Application Project...'.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I've ever seen that feature, even in the old version. An alternative is to make a new Java Project, right click it > **Google** > **Web Toolkit Settings...** and check off **Use Google Web Toolkit**

Comment: I do think you saw this toolbar button but maybe you just can't remember the button tooltip text; I added screenshot to my question; Watch it please